# How to acess to event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, geolocation

1120: Access of undefined property event.
How to get this event /event.latitude.toString()/ to mail it

```
function onMapReady(e: Event): void {
if (Geolocation.isSupported) {
    var geo = new Geolocation();
    geo.setRequestedUpdateInterval(100);
    geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, geolocationUpdateHandler);
}
}

function geolocationUpdateHandler(event: GeolocationEvent): void {
trace("lat:" + event.latitude.toString() + " - ");
trace("long:" + event.longitude.toString() + "° - ");
}

ve_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, send);
function send(e: MouseEvent): void {
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:test@test.lv?body=</br>  latitude=" +  event.latitude.toString() + "</br>  longitude=" + event.longitude.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you are going to want to increase the `setRequestedUpdateInterval` value. 100ms is, I believe, faster than the minimum interval for any OS out there. Even if you could update it that often, it would destroy battery life. A client asked me to reduce it to 1 minute (60000ms) for their app, against my judgement, and we saw their Galaxy S4 lose 20% battery over the course of a 90 minute meeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'll try to explain this.
If you want to use the longitude and latitude values from your Geolocation event when you click your mouse on something, you need to store those values somewhere because MouseEvent does not have those properties. Only GeolocationEvent has those.

How do you solve this then? simple, create variables that hold the latitude and longitude values that are retrieved in your geolocationUpdateHandler(...) method.

Sorta like this

```
var latitude:Number = 0;
var longitude:Number = 0;    

function onMapReady(e: Event): void {
    if (Geolocation.isSupported) {
        var geo = new Geolocation();
        geo.setRequestedUpdateInterval(100);
        geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, geolocationUpdateHandler);
    }
    }

    function geolocationUpdateHandler(event: GeolocationEvent): void {
    trace("lat:" + event.latitude.toString() + " - ");
    trace("long:" + event.longitude.toString() + "° - ");
    latitude = event.latitude;
    longitude = event.longitude;
    }

    ve_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, send);
    function send(e: MouseEvent): void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:test@test.lv?body=</br>  latitude=" +  latitude.toString() + "</br>  longitude=" + longitude.toString()));
    }
```

Comment: latitude = event.latitude;
longitude = event.longitude;

Comment: 1120: Access of undefined property

Comment: oh yes, sorry, saw it too late.

Comment: now only need to start this function onMapReady atomatic

Answer (score 0):

Change this part :

```
function send(e: MouseEvent): void
```

to this:

```
function send(event: MouseEvent): void
```

Comment: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property latitude through a reference with static type flash.events:MouseEvent.

Comment: That's because MouseEvent does not have a latitude/longitude property. GeolocationEvent has those properties.

Comment: 1120: Access of undefined property latitude.
latitude = event.latitude;
longitude = event.longitude;